# Angular post object with arrays in it

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to post an object which has some properties and arrays in it.
Properties are submitted just fine, but arrays within object are not serialized back in a MVC.NET Controller. 
In this example page is mapped properly, but array object (locations) is always `null` in the controller.
Any suggestions?

```
//add some data
$scope.formData = {
 Page: 1,
 Locations: []
};
$scope.formData.Locations.push({
 LocationID: 1,
 LocationType: 1
});
$scope.formData.Locations.push({
 LocationID: 2,
 LocationType: 2
});

//post method
$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'myurl',
 params: $scope.formData,
}).then(function successCallback(
 response) {
 //do something
}, function errorCallback(response) {
 //do something

});
```

Serverside model

```
public class SearchAuctionData
{     
    public int Page { get; set; }
    public List<SmallLocation> Locations { get; set; }
}

public class SmallLocation
{
    public short LocationID { get; set; }
    public short LocationType { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<JsonResult> GetAuctions(SearchAuctionData data)
{
//do somethng
   return Json(result);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'myurl',
 params: $scope.formData,
```

Should be:

```
$http({
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'myurl',
 data: $scope.formData,
```

Even better, use a service (make sure to inject it to the controller):

```
app.factory("MyService", ["$http", function($http){
    return {
        postItem: function(url, item) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: 'POST',
                data: item
            });
        }
    }
}]);
```

**Inside the controller**

```
MyService.postItem('/path/to/c#/controller', $scope.formData).then(successCallback).catch(failureCallback);
```

Comment: what a oversight by me :D. Replaced params with data and all works fine.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "`null` in the controller"?

After your POST request ?

Or printing `$scope.formData.Locations` before POST call and that's `null`?

Comment: in the controller on the server Locations object is always null.
It maps only root properties of my model, but not arrays. I've added server side code to my question.

Comment: I see @KKKKKKKK found your problem. Just to make sure you don't waste anymore time on that mistake like i already did, POST needs `data`, but GET needs `params`, just so you know :P !